# 2-opt algorithm not generating the right routes

Tags: javascript, arrays, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to generate [2-opt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt) routes in javascript using the standard 2-opt mechanism, I made the following implementation:

```js
// Simple one 2-opt swap
function swap(arr, i, k) {
  return arr.slice(0, i - 1).concat(arr.slice(i - 1, k).reverse(), arr.slice(k));
}

// Complete 2-opt swaps
function swaps(arr) {
  swapies = []; // array of possible swaps
  for (var i = 2; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var k = i + 1; k < arr.length; k++) {
      swapies.push(swap(arr, i, k));
    }
  }
  return swapies;
}

a = [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0] // route example
swaps(a)
/* =>  [ [ 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0 ],
  [ 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0 ],
  [ 0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0 ],
  [ 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 0 ],
  [ 0, 3, 4, 2, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0 ] ]
 */
```

As far as I know, the above output is correct apart from the **[0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 0]** swap. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this? Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce your output either in JS or Python:
[0,3,1,2,4,0], 
[0,2,3,1,4,0], 
[0,4,2,3,1,0], 
[0,1,2,3,4,0], 
[0,1,4,2,3,0], 
[0,1,3,4,2,0]

Comment: @CaptainTrunky Thanks for letting me know, I updated the input  array!

Comment: What's wrong with `[0,4,2,1,3,0]` output in your opinion?

Comment: @DAle I'm not entirely sure but it's the same path in term of cost as the input [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0]

Comment: @xde013 But this algorithm is not cost-aware. It just generates a set of reasonable paths for you. It's your responsibility to compare them and choose the best one.

Comment: @CaptainTrunky I'm fully aware of it, I just want it to generate the right paths from the input path..

Comment: @xde013 But all of them seems to be correct. :) If some of them have the same cost - it is fine at this stage, you will deal with it later.